# What faster, reading from txt file or from mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I reads some doubt that part saying that reading from file faster than reading (searching) from mysql table.

I have about 2000 raw, and the speed is very important factor for my application.

What do you think about this ? to add the 2000 rows to a txt file and when i need to check a vlalue if it exist in the file to read the file or to make a new table and insert the 2000 rows to the table and to make indexes in the search fields ?
I am using PHP (codeIgniter framework)

Thank you

Comment: When talking about performance, we don't "think about" things. We **measure.**

Comment: You also need to consider future data maintenance, how easily will you be able to delete and alter the data in future

Comment: @LemuelBotha it is a static data that i didn't need to make changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it depends. MySQL is able to cache a lot, and make use of in memory indexes for finding information. If you (always) read from a file, you always have disk I/O, which is very slow in general. Of course it depends on your hardware too. A big raid system, SSD disks, they will speed up file access dramatically. Also, the OS might cache file blocks if you read them multiple times. Still, MySQL will also benefit from these advantages, since it also stores its data in files in the end, and has the other optimizations on top.

That said, MySQL is a generic database. If you have the time and knowledge to write a specialized data storage for your specific purpose, it might be faster.

Anyway, there is no generic answer to your question.